# 'File path' use causing program exit in Python 3

Tags: windows, exit, filepath, python-3.3

I have downloaded a set of html files and saved the file paths which I saved them to in a .txt file. It has each path on a new line. I wanted to look at the first file in the list and then itterate through the whole list, opening the files and extracting data before going on to the next file.

My code works fine with a single path put in directly (for the first file) as:

```
path = r'C:\path\to\file.html'
```

and works if I itterate through the text file using:

```
file_list_fp = r'C:\path\to\file_with_pathlist.txt'
with open(file_list_fp, 'r') as file_list:
for filepath in file_list:
    pathend = filepath.find('\n')
    path = file[:pathend]
    q = open(path, 'r').read()
```

but it fails when I try getting a single path using either:

```
with open(file_list_fp, 'r') as file_list:

    path_n = file_list.readline()
    end = path_n.find('\n')
    path_bad1 = path_n[:end]
```

or:

```
with open(file_list_fp, 'r') as file_list:    

    path_bad2 = file_list.readline().split('\n')[0]
```

With these two my code exits just after that point. I can't figure out why. Any pointers very welcome. (I'm using Python 3.3.1 on windows.)

Comment: 1. You can use `filepath.rstrip()` to remove the newline. 2. Maybe there are '\r' at the end of the files

Comment: 3. What is the traceback? you may need to open it in `'rb'` mode if a `UnicodeDecodeError` occurs

Comment: @User there is no traceback - it doesn't error it just stops the program as if it came to a natural end - hence the confusion!